# Error while importing datashader

Tags: python, ctypes, ffi, datashader

**Code:**
`import datashader as ds`

**Error:**
`self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found`

**Detailed Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\ffi.py", line 40, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(_lib_dir, _lib_name))
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\datashader\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .core import Canvas
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\datashader\core.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .utils import Dispatcher, ngjit
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\datashader\utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numba as nb
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import runtests, decorators
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import config, sigutils
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\numba\config.py", line 10, in <module>
    import llvmlite.binding as ll
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .dylib import *
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\dylib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\ffi.py", line 45, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(_lib_name)
  File "D:\Adarsh\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: how did you install `datashader`?

Comment: Hi Ashafix thanks for your intrest in resolving the issue. I installed from cmd window. setup.py install

Comment: This is an issue with your install of llvmlite. Installing it via pip is a bit of a pain, so I recommend using conda (http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). Then just do `conda install -c bokeh datashader`.